# How to create complex query parameters in Restangular

Tags: angularjs, rest, restangular

I need to create a fairly complex query string in Restangular.

```
http://vdmta.rd.mycompany.net//people?anr=Smith&attrs=givenName,displayName,name,cn
```

How do I do this?

So far I am OK getting as far as ?anr=Smith using this:

```
return Restangular.all('/people').getList({anr:searchTerm});
```

The last part attrs=x,y,x lets me control which attributes I want back in the search and could change per request I make.

Any advice appreciated.

Regards

i

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to simply add another query parameter where the value is your comma separated list of attributes.

```
var attributes = ['givenName' , 'displayName']; // attributes you require for the request
var attributesAsString = attributes.join();

return Restangular.all('/people').getList({
    anr : searchTerm,
    attrs: attributesAsString
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is attributes an array here? Or do I have to build the comma separated list and pass it in as a string?

Comment: You could easily provide an array and convert it into a comma separated string (it looks like a comma separated string is what you need, right?). Updated the answer to show. Simply using [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).